# Ubuntu - Настройка предустановленных избранных элементов в dash-панели в CUBIC Live-CD образе

Tags: ubuntu, config, dash

Решил побаловаться с CUBIC, создать свой мега-дистр с блэкджеком и симпатичными обоями, и вот, вроде бы все получается, но уперся в такую беду - не могу найти файл, в котором можно подредактировать список закрепленных в dash-панели избранных программ. Хочу удалить оттуда лишнее барахло и добавить чего-нибудь полезное. Пожалуйста, подскажите, где их искать. Так же интересно, где можно выпилить это галимое окно предварительной настройки, которое предлагает создать "online accounts" и отсылать Canonical какие-то там данные. Хочется, чтобы система была полностью готова к работе прямо вот сразу при запуске в Live-CD режиме и не задавала идиотских вопросов. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так, хорошо что обсудил эту тему со своим котом. Решение такое: на вашем компьютере, где вы запустили CUBIC, сначала приводите dash-панель к тому виду, какой вам нравится. Затем открываете Nautilus, идете в папку ~/.config/dconf
В chroot окружении Кубика создаете каталог
mkdir /home/madmentat/.config/dconf
Переходите в него
cd /home/madmentat/.config/dconf
и тупо методом drug-and-drop перетаскиваете мышъю из Наутилуса в ваш Кубик файл "user", после чего жмякаете кнопочку "Copy" и радуетесь жизни.
Осталось только избавиться от безобразия, выделенного красным на следующем скриншоте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
apt purge gnome-initial-setup -y
```